# VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) with meanjs and vagrant

Tags: node.js, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, meanjs

I am trying to run mean.js project based on vagrant , but I get the following error with the `vagrant up` command on `ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bi`t.

```
        There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
        for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

        Command: ["startvm", "d660b7d6-06a3-49bc-8b90-cbad92632c11", "--type", "headless"]

        Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'pets_default_1473142645576_38190' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
        VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

Comment: Similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/527699/i-am-getting-the-same-error-everytime-i-try-to-boot-ubuntu-on-virtualbox/1210967#1210967

Comment: I found this to caused but pending updates for Ubuntu. Running the update and restarting fixed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the using following steps:

I have completely remove older VirtualBox versions before installing VirtualBox-5.0 !

1. Uninstall VirtualBox

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"
   ```
2. Update the software repositories

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Clean up

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove | sudo apt-get autoclean | sudo apt-get clean
   ```
4. Setup API repository (For Ubuntu 14.04 ("Trusty"))

   ```
   echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
   ```
5. Setup Oracle Key

   ```
   wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```

6.Install Oracle Virtualbox

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
    Start Virtualbox
    virtualbox
```

For more help check to [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2016/09/mean-stack-development-with-vagrant.html).

Answer (score 6):

I have reinstalled virtual box and the issue has been solved for me.

On my mac while installing virtual box, It has not allowed me to install. So i went system preference ->  security & privacy - > general - 'allow apps download from' -> click on the "allow" button.

I have successfully installed virtual box after the above changes on system preference.

Kitchen converge -> successfully done.

Answer (score 5):

I was using **macOS** and I had this error after updating VirtualBox. I solved the error by going to:
**System Preferences** --> **Security & Privacy** and then clicked on lock to make changes. Then, I clicked on "***Allow***" as shown in the picture below:

[image]

After you make the changes, a restart is requested by the system, after restart the command should work just ok :)

Answer (score 4):

Move to directory:

```
cd /sbin/
```

Run script:

```
sudo ./vboxconfig
```

Start VM:

```
VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless
```

It works:)

Root this problem - system updating. VBox updated partially. This script fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, but [Santosh Shinde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39366133/10907864) helped me to figure it out.

**I, however, want to add to it:**

After uninstalling every old/previous version of Virtualbox available on your PC:

```
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"
```

And cleaning your system:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Rather than installing Virtualbox from the Apt repository of Ubuntu, simply visit the [downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) page of Virtualbox, to download the most current version of Virtualbox.

This is because the Apt repository may not have the latest version of Virtualbox.

Comment: Don't do this. This is a bad practice, for the very reason you implicitly mention yourself: always having up-to-date software. Always use package managers when you can, **precisely** because they allow you to automatically update installed packages when new versions arrive. Installing a downloaded binary will never be updated unless you manually do it all again. @Santosh Shinde's answer precisely explains how to use Oracle's own repository for apt packages of VirtualBox so that you always have the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my virtualbox linux host was having an outdated vboxdrv kernel module.

I did the whole remove VirtualBox package, then reinstall, but this old version kernel module remained.

Manually deleted the unwanted module, then freshly reinstalled latest VirtualBox, then usual vboxconfig to rebuild the latest modules, and we're done.

`/usr/bin/vboxmanage startvm Win10-Server --type headless` now working as expected.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error after install some cripto plugin to Chrome.Then see that Virtual box extension is not working under root and user. In my linux distributive `/opt` owner was changed to user by cripto plugin installator. Changing `/opt`to root owner has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen on a FreeBSD box where vagrant wasn't involved at all.

```
[root@freebsdserver ~]# vboxmanage startvm yavm
Waiting for VM "yavm" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'yavm' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 6
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

In this case it's because "freebsdserver" is running headless. The fix was to run:

`# vboxmanage startvm yavm --type headless`